# Universal Links IOS9

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Seems that Apple is moving away from the custom scheme mechanism for opening apps via linking.
With custom schemes if you were to try to open an custom scheme registered by your app, the applications would open and the javascript function handleOpenURL would handle the call.

Does worklight support the new "Universal Links" method in IOS9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal Linking was not tested as part of iOS 9 support. If linking is required continue to work with the custom scheme option for the time being.

Edit: tested and found to be working.

Comment: When did it also call the same handleOpenURL function?

Answer (score 1):

In our project worklight didn't trigger handleOpenURL function for Universal Links functionality out of the box.

So, we used the following solution:

1) Native layer plugin

MyAppDelegate+UniversalLinksPlugin.h

```
#import "rr.h"


@interface MyAppDelegate (UniversalLinksPlugin)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler;

@end
```

MyAppDelegate+UniversalLinksPlugin.m

```
#import "rr.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation MyAppDelegate (UniversalLinksPlugin)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {

    NSLog(@"Universal links plugin: starting application launch handling.");
    // ignore activities that are not for Universal Links
    if (![userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb] || userActivity.webpageURL == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString* url = [userActivity.webpageURL absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"Universal links plugin: the following url is used for the application launch %@", url);

    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [data setValue:url forKey:@"url"];
    [[WL sharedInstance] sendActionToJS:@"handleURL" withData:data];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

2) config.xml update:

```
<feature name="UniversalLinksPlugin">
   <param name="ios-package" value="UniversalLinksPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

3) iphone/js/main.js update:

```
/**
 * UL links handling
 */
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    WL.App.addActionReceiver ("ULReceiver", function(received) {
        if (received.action === "handleURL") {
            WL.Logger.debug('Inside handle URL action receiver. Provided url: ' + received.data.url);
            handleOpenURL(received.data.url);
        }
    });

}, false);
```

This is it. I really hope that this will help to someone )